# Find and return pattern in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns.  One column is a part number and the other is a description.  Within that description, there may or may not be a ratio listed (50:1, 25:1, etc).  It can be anywhere in the description and some may not have a ratio at all.

[image: Example]

I would want to return in a 3rd column just the 50:1 or 25:1 portion.  The other rows would return nothing or null.  I have tried ltrims, rtrims, charindex, etc.  I can't seem to get it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: SQL isn't a string processing language. What you describe would require regular expression support (not available in T-SQL) and even then it couldn't use any indexes. It would be easier to modify the program that loads the data to parse and extract that pattern and store it in a separate field.

Comment: You could, probably get rows that have a ratio in them, using `LIKE '%[0-9]:[0-9]%`, but that's probably perform awfully. Extracting the ratio after that though is going to be a real ... in T-SQL. I agree with  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: if its always nn:n then this is reasonably simple (although ugly) with patindex()

Comment: if the values are static, patindex can work.  but if there are varying ratios that are unknown, then patindex can find if a ratio exists, but you won't know the length of the found ratio in order to substring it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `PATINDEX`, but it will not be very helpful if new ratios can be added. You'd have to expand the search.

```
create table test (
    id int identity primary key not null,
    itemNumber varchar(50) not null,
   description varchar(100) not null  
 );

insert into test (itemNumber, description)
select 'asdfsdfa', 'FLKDWEFlkjf50:1' UNION ALL
select 'eweEFEW34281', 'FSDlskdfFJ' UNION ALL
select '1324SFDAS', 'DFSLd25:1' UNION ALL
select '1324SFDAS', 'DFSLd2:1';;

select itemNumber, description,
  case when PATINDEX('%[0-9]:[0-9]%', description) > 0 then '50:1'
       when PATINDEX('%[0-9]:[0-9]%', description) > 0 then '25:1'
       else '' end as ratio
   from test;
```

Here's an example of how this will work for varying length ratios; you can see how messy this can get with dynamic ratios.

```
select itemNumber, description,
  case when PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9]%', description) > 0 
          then SUBSTRING(description, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9]%', description), 5)
       when PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9]%', description) > 0 
          then  SUBSTRING(description, patindex('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9]%', description), 4)
       when PATINDEX('%[0-9]:[0-9]%', description) > 0 
          then SUBSTRING(description, patindex('%[0-9]:[0-9]%', description), 3)
       else '' end as ratio
   from test;
```

If you can add a ratio column to your actual table and run code like this once for backfilling the data, that would be the best approach.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e7f00/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way... feel free to add as many values as you like to the `UNION` to test.  It pulls back rows where there is a ratio, as specified by `:` with numbers on each side.

```
;with cte(vals)
AS
(
SELECT 'hgfhy10:1isdlfjgirj' 
UNION SELECT '25:1isodgji'
UNION SELECT 'gfhy100:1'
UNION SELECT 'gfhy100.1'
UNION SELECT 'ksljdil'
UNION SELECT '30:111a'
UNION SELECT '40:155'
UNION SELECT 'A:A'
)

select
    vals
    ,case 
        when patindex('%[0-9]%',substring(vals,1,charindex(':',vals))) = 0 then null
        else substring(substring(vals,1,charindex(':',vals)),patindex('%[0-9]%',substring(vals,1,charindex(':',vals))),9999)
    end
    +
    case
        when patindex('%[a-z]%',substring(vals,charindex(':',vals) + 1,9999)) = 1 then null
        else left(  substring(vals,charindex(':',vals) + 1,9999),
                    case 
                        when patindex('%[a-z]%',substring(vals,charindex(':',vals) + 1,9999)) = 0 
                        then 9999
                        else patindex('%[a-z]%',substring(vals,charindex(':',vals) + 1,9999)) - 1 
                    end
                    )
    end
from cte
```